# how to find the column address(only the letter) in VBA and express columns function with variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and replace part of my string using VBA within a certain range. For example, whenever my code found the word "CL", I want it to replace the sigma headers from next column onwards with "ideal sigma". But how do i find the cell's column letter after i found the cell address which contain letters and numbers? At the same time im also not sure whether i express my columns() function correctly with variables...

```
Sub testing2()

Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Dim lastcolletter As String
    Dim firstcolletter As String
    Dim detailedcolletter As String
    Dim ra As Range

lastcolumn = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim ra As Range

Set ra = Worksheets("Data").Cells.Find(What:="CL", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
    detailedcolletter = ra.Address 'detailedcolletter address = D2 here
    'how to extract just the letter here only?

  i = "Sigma"
k = "Ideal Sigma"

lastcolletter = Col_Letter(lastcolumn)
Columns("firstcolletter" & ":" & "lastcolletter").Replace What:=i, replacement:=k, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
'not sure whether i expressed columns() function with variables correctly here

End Sub


Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")

End Function
```

Currently

[image]

Expected

[image]

Updated code

```
Sub testing2()

Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Dim lastcolletter As String
    Dim firstcolletter As String
    Dim detailedcolletter As String
    Dim ra As Range

    lastcolumn = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="CL", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
        detailedcolletter = ra.Address 'detailedcolletter address = D4 here
        'how to extract just the letter here only?
        detailedcolletter = colLetter(ra.Column)

      i = "Sigma"
    k = "Ideal Sigma"

    lastcolletter = Col_Letter(lastcolumn)
    Columns("detailedcolletter" & ":" & "lastcolletter").Replace What:=i, Replacement:=k, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False '<----type mismatch over here

    End Sub


Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")

End Function

Function colLetter(col As Long) As String
    colLetter = Split(Columns(col).Address(, 0), ":")(0)
End Function
```

latest pic
[image]

current pic

[image]

Comment: `vArr` will be an array, so you will need to say `Col_letter=vArr(1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60690998/6600940

Comment: Sidenote: Try to use explicit sheet references when you refer to range objects like `Cells`.

Comment: No need to find letters, use range `Offset` and `Resize` methods.

Comment: @BrakNicku Im quite unfamiliar with the offset and resize method and thats why im heading towards the find and replace method..

Comment: @JvdV i have updated the codes...

Comment: Excel doesn't work with column letters. It identifies columns by numbers. Specify a cell as `Cells([Row Number], [Column Number])`. Obtain the column number from a range with `Clm = Range.Column` or `Clm = Range("A1").Column` or `Clm = Columns("AB").Column`, in fact also `Clm = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question you could use the following function

```
Function colLetter(col As Long) As String
    colLetter = Split(Columns(col).Address(, 0), ":")(0)
End Function
```

In your case you need to call the function with the column property

```
Sub Testit()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("D2")
    Debug.Print colLetter(rg.Column)
End Sub
```

In your code then

```
detailedcolletter = colLetter(ra.Column)
```

**PS** One could fix your code like that (no need of the above function)

```
Sub testing2()

    Dim i As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim lastcolumn As Long

    Dim ra As Range
    Dim hdrRow As Long



    Set ra = Cells.Find(What:="CL", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    hdrRow = ra.Row - 1
    lastcolumn = Worksheets("Data").Cells(hdrRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    i = "Sigma"
    k = "Ideal Sigma"

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Worksheets("Data")
    With wks
        .Range(.Cells(hdrRow, ra.Column + 1), .Cells(hdrRow, lastcolumn)).Replace What:=i, replacement:=k, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

**PS2** Updated the code by adding a variable for the header row. Please be aware that the code has still some pitfalls you have to take care of as for example code will crash if there is no CL at all in the sheet or it is found in row 1.

Comment: i have used your suggestion(the one that is function col_letter) and there is this mismatch error as labelled on my code..

Comment: is it possible to not just restrict to first row only? Like CL and the sigma headers may lie other ranges as well and i want similar situation to happen in 1st row to happen to this as well as depicts in my latest picture..

Comment: Yes, but question is how do you determine the header row?

Comment: im not sure about your question but whenever "CL" is in the worksheet, the headers that i want to convert to "ideal sigma" lies right above "CL"...

Comment: it converts the left side of the sigma instead of the right as shown in my "current pic", have i miss out something?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to replace the 1 in `lastcolumn = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` with `hdr Row`. Code updated

Answer (score 1):

Use `range.offset` to get an array to be replaced, then you can use `range.replace`, try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i as string, k as string,index as integer
i = "Sigma":k = "Ideal Sigma"
With ActiveSheet
Dim rng As Range
Index = .Cells.Find("CL").Column
    .Columns(Index).Resize(, .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=2, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) _
    .Column - Index + 1).Replace What:=i, Replacement:=k, LookAt:=xlPart
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks alot,but it only works for the 1st row tho. Like what i want it to happen to other ranges as well as shown in my latest picture...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a re-write of your code. Most of the `Find` properties aren't strictly necessary because they just repeat the defaults but I actually not only like to have them in my code but even list them out clearly (for easy reading) so that I know what has been set without referring to the MSDN handbook for what is the default.

```
Sub testing2()

    Dim Fnd As Range

    With Worksheets("Data")
        Set Fnd = .Rows(1).Find(What:="CL", _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Set Fnd = .Range(Fnd.Offset(0, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft))
            Fnd.Replace What:="Sigma", _
                        Replacement:="ideal Sigma", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i got an object doesn't support this property at the Set Fnd line? Why is this so?

Comment: That's because there is a syntax error in the hastily written code. My apologies! I forgot to specify the range in which to search - in fact just `.Rows(1)` and have since edited my answer.